# Rails 5.1, sum by currency with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, sum, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

I have a problem with a SUM calculation. I have multiple currency in a table, I have users, I have groups and I have a bets table. The user can join a group via member (user_id and group_id). And the user can share his bet via groupbet (bet_id and member_id). I don't enter in detail here because all this works properly.

I would like to do some SUM calculation in the group view (show). This is where I'd like to display the total amount of money the members of the group spend for there bet. I also would like to use chartkick in the mix to show some nice graph.

This is what I have so far

My controller :

```
m =  Member.where(group_id: @group.id)
gs = Groupbet.where(member_id: m)

@tasks = gs.joins(:bet).select("bets.*, sum(amount) as total")

@amount =  gs.joins(:bet).
      select(:symb, 'bets.*, sum(amount) AS amount').
      where(bet_id: { id: @current_user.bets.all.map(&:id) }).
      group(:symb)
```

@tasks works but SUM all the spendings from the group, that's cool, but I have several currencies so the amount is not correct. This is why I came up with @amount which in the view :

```
<% @amount.each do |amount| %>
<%= '%.02f' % "#{amount.amount}" %>
<%= "#{amount.symb}" %>
<% end %>
```

display nothing at all.

the :symb is one of my Currency column btw. In currency I have name and symb, where symbole is this : € or $ for example. In my spending table I have a column amount and the currency_id.

My relations :

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :bets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :bets

end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_token :auth_token

    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :members, source: :user
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"

    has_many :links, through: :grouplinks
    has_many :grouplinks, through: :members

    has_many :bets, through: :groupbets
    has_many :groupbets, through: :members

    has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy

    def to_param
        auth_token
    end

end

class Groupbet < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :bet
    belongs_to :member

end

class Member < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :grouplinks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groupbets, dependent: :destroy

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}

end

class Bet < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :currency
    has_many :groupbets, dependent: :destroy

end

class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password

  has_many :bets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :currencies, through: :bets

  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
  has_one :owned_group, foreign_key: "owner_id", class_name: "Group"
end
```

Links has nothing to do here but yeah...

---

I'm also using groupdate and for chartkick I don't really know because when a user creates a bet he can actually go on his profile and check all the bets he did, as well in a chart. To display this chart, which is working, I'm doing like so :

My helper

```
def expenses_bet_amount_per_month
@current_user.bets.all.joins(:currency).group('currencies.symb').group_by_month(:date, format: "%B %Y").sum(:amount)
end
```

date is the date when the user create the bet. Don't ask why I didn't use created_at, doesn't matter :)

And my view :

```
<%= column_chart expenses_bet_amount_per_month %>
```

That works. For one single user. But for the group I don't know how I could make that happen.

If anyone can save the situation ? Thank you very much

EDIT :

The code for the single user :

```
def sums_by_currency_total
        Currency.joins(:bets).
            select(:symb, 'SUM(bets.amount) AS amount').
            where(bets: { id: user_bets_total.map(&:id) }).
            group(:symb)
end

def user_spendings_total
        user.bets.all
end
```

That works for one user. Display the SUM from all bets per currency. But for a group ? I don't know

Comment: I edited the post, the controller wasn't correct

Comment: User bets have a currency? You didn’t post this model which is relevant.  Shouldn’t bets have a bookmaker account which has a currency instead?

Comment: Yes they can bet in different currency, but the currency model has the bets in for example

Comment: Ok. I am Smart Bet Tracker owner. Check if you find something useful in our architecture (we don’t have groups right now), but a lot of functionality may be similar to the one you want.

Comment: I'm actually doing a different thing. I managed to display all the SUM from each currency but for a single user I edited the main post

Answer (score 0):

Ok people I managed !!!!

I share the code in case anybody is interested :

```
def sums_by_currency_group
    m =  Member.where(group_id: @group.id)
    gs = Groupbet.where(member_id: m)
    Currency.joins(:bets)
            .select(:symb, 'SUM(bets.amount) AS amount')
            .where(bets: { id: gs.all.map(&:bet_id) })
            .group(:symb)
end
```

In the view :

```
<% sums_by_currency_group.each do |sum| %>
<%= '%.02f' % "#{sum.amount}" %> <%= "#{sum.symb}" %>
<% end %>
```

And there we go. All the SUM from the bets that are shared in each group.

I also solved the problem for chart kick :

```
def bets_amount_per_month_group
    m =  Member.where(group_id: @group.id)
    gs = Groupbet.where(member_id: m)
    Currency.joins(:bets)
        .where(bets: { id: gs.all.map(&:bet_id) })
        .group('currencies.symb')
        .group_by_month(:date, format: "%B %Y")
        .sum(:amount)
end
```

In the view :

```
<%= column_chart bets_amount_per_month_group %>
```

Et voila ! Nice chart of all the bets shared in the group. I used the same method as the calculation and it worked !! Olé !!